# #1064.You have an error in your SQL syntax;check manual that corresponds to MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1

Tags: mysql

I have following code. I am getting an error like:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1

MySQL code:

```
set session group_concat_max_len = 8192*50;
SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'select id, "',
      c.column_name,
      '" as word from limesurvey.lime_survey_697389 '
    ) SEPARATOR ' UNION ALL '
  ) INTO @sql
FROM information_schema.columns c
where c.table_name = 'limesurvey.lime_survey_697389'
  and c.column_name like '697389%'
  order by c.ordinal_position;


SET @sql 
  = CONCAT('select id, word
           from
           (', @sql, ') x order by id');


PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Can anyone help here? I am new to MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>You cannot define NULL value to @sql. Instead you can try like this:</strike>

```
SET @sql = '';
```

**EDIT:**

You need to execute the above code inside a stored program or function. The MYSQL docs says:

> MySQL supports the IF, CASE, ITERATE, LEAVE LOOP, WHILE, and REPEAT
>   constructs for flow control within stored programs.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the [9.4 User-Defined Variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-variables.html) `@sql` has NULL?

Try:

```
...
SET @`sql` := (SELECT IF(
                  @`sql` IS NULL, 'SELECT \'@`sql` IS NULL\' `error`',
                  CONCAT('SELECT `id`, `word`
                  FROM (', @`sql`, ') `x` ORDER BY `id`')
              ));
...
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4ce09c/14)</kbd>